# Оформление Input type="text"

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, возможно ли сменить оформление текстового поля input?
Если это возможно, подтолкните в нужное направление.

Смотрел в Googl`e, ни чего внятного не нашел.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 26):

Лучше будет учесть все

```
input[type="text"] {
   border: 1px solid #cccccc; //цвет рамки
   border-radius: 3px; //закругление углов (общее)
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px; //закругление углов (Google Chrome)
   -moz-border-radius: 3px; //закругление углов (FireFox)
   -khtml-border-radius: 3px; //закругление углов (Safari)
   background: #ffffff !important; // желательно прописывать, так как в Chrome при сохранных данных оно может быть желтым
   outline: none; // удаляет обводку в браузерах хром(желтая) и сафари(синяя)
   height: 24px; // высота на свое усмотрение
   width: 120px; // ширина на свое усмотрение
   color: #cccccc; //цвет шрифта в обычном состоянии
   font-size: 11px; // Размер шрифта
   font-family: Tahoma; // Стиль шрифта
}
```

Можно также добавить стиль при на нажатии(фокусе) на поле

```
input[type="text"]:focus {
  color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000
}
```

Писать

```
input[type="text"]
```

не обязательно можно просто

```
input
```

тогда свойство будет применено для всех инпатов.

Answer (score 5):

Для всех Input с type="text"

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно. В css пишешь стиль, а input'у присваивашь нужный класс.
Вот пример из админки DLE.
В `CSS`

```
.edit {
    border:1px solid #9E9E9E;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #FFF;
}

.bk {
    background:#fff url(images/shadow.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Ну и к `input`'у пишешь:

```
<input class="edit bk" type="text" name="ololo">
```

[Картинка из bk](http://dle-news.ru/engine/skins/images/shadow.png)

Comment: @Morty, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.